# Unmountable XFS filesystem

Tags: filesystems, xfs

I'm a bit hysterical right now because I am unable to mount my external hard drive. I formatted it to XFS about a month ago and moved some files there this morning (a virtual hard drive, among others, to save space on my filled local drive) and for some reason, the USB cable just came off. When I plugged it back, it refused to mount. I ran `xfs_repair -L /dev/sdb1` and that didn't work. I ran `xfs_admin -U generate /dev/sdb1` and I got a new kind of error:

> xfs superblock has incompatible features (0x4)

or something along those lines. What can be done to fix the filesystem? Or at least if I can get a list of the files using xfs utilities, it would make a huge difference!

Answer (score 1):

To quote Archimedes:

> *Eureka! I've found it!*

The problem is that when you invoke the command `xfs_admin -U generate /dev/sdXY` the *generate* parameter causes xfs_admin to flip the incompatible bit to *on*, so that older kernels cannot use the filesystem. An explanation can be found in the following quote provided by *RTFM*:

```
xfs_admin(8)

...

-U uuid
          Set the UUID of the filesystem to uuid.  A sample UUID looks
          like this: "c1b9d5a2-f162-11cf-9ece-0020afc76f16".  The uuid
          may also be nil, which will set the filesystem UUID to the
          null UUID.  The uuid may also be generate, which will generate
          a new UUID for the filesystem.  Note that on CRC-enabled
          filesystems, this will set an incompatible flag such that
          older kernels will not be able to mount the filesystem.  To
          remove this incompatible flag, use restore, which will restore
          the original UUID and remove the incompatible feature flag as
          needed.
```

To reverse this, simply run `xfs_admin -U restore /dev/sdXY`, and you should be able to mount the partition again.
What's strange is that the machine that was used to generate the UUID is the machine that's running the latest kernel (4.2.5-1-ARCH, okay, maybe not the latest, but UUID *should* imply that this machine is not excluded from compatibility). Anyway what's important is that the problem was solved.